# Unable to launch list view owing to constructor error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to get my list view to appear but it won't don't do so when running my app due to a constructor error that I don't know how to fix. How can this issue be resolved?

**FragmentWCLine.java**

```
public class FragmentWCLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ListView listView;

    private class WC {
        private CharSequence station;
        private CharSequence zone;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;
        private Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass;

        public WC(int stationResId, int zoneResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass, Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass) {
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.station = getResources().getString(stationResId);
            this.zone = getResources().getString(zoneResId);
            }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return station.toString(); }
        public String getzone(){ return zone.toString(); }
    }

    private static WC[] mWC;

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_line, container, false);

        mWC = new WC[]{
                new WC(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
                new WC(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)
        };

        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_wc);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mWC));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].fragmentClass));
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].activityClass));
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView station;
            TextView zone;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        WC[] mWC;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, WC[] samples) {
            this.mWC = samples;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mWC.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mWC[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.station = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                viewHolder.zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.station.setText(mWC[position].station);
            viewHolder.zone.setText(mWC[position].getzone());
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Error:(54, 17) error: constructor WC in class FragmentWCLine.WC cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,int,Class<? extends Activity>,Class<? extends Fragment>
found: int,int,Class<WCBankActivity>,Class<FragmentWCBank>
reason: actual argument Class<WCBankActivity> cannot be converted to Class<? extends Activity> by method invocation conversion
```

**errors occurance**

```
mWC = new WC[]{
                new WC(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
                new WC(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)
        };
```

[image]

Comment: I did not get compile errors when I added the related code you posted, as best as I can. Perhaps post code for WCBankActivity for resolving the error on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that **WCBankActivity** extends *Activity* class and **FragmentWCBank** *Fragment*.
It looks to me that **WCBankActivity** isn't *Activity* for some reason but I wouldn't know looking at this code.

Hope it helped a bit.